# When exchanging data between a browser and a server, the data can only be text. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, json, http

I understood why we are using JSON to exchange data between browser and server in place of XML  but I could not understand why we are using only string type of JSON even we have six different value datatype, I mean why we can't use integer or Boolean or any other value datatype.
   Hope you guys understand what I'm trying to say, Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be able to send boolean or numeric value with JSON. The requirement though is that request needs to be converted to plain text because of HTTP used for communication which is a text based protocol by design.

Comment: To clarify: you don’t understand why HTTP payloads are text, or you believe that even when using JSON, you must only use JSON text values, and not JSON booleans etc?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, the limitation is because of the way data needs to be **encoded to be sent over HTTP and ultimately over the wire**. You json object (or xml,etc) is ultimately just a payload for HTTP (which is just a payload for tcp in turn and so on).

HTTP inherently does not and should not identify data types in payload, it is just an array for HTTP. You can select how to represent this array i.e. how to *encode* it; It can be string (ascii, utf-8, etc) or binary but it has to be uniform for the whole payload.

HTTP does offer different encoding methods of payload which can be interpreted by the receiver by looking at the *content-type* header and accordingly decode the data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: First of all thank a lot for your valuable answer....but I have one more query like why do we need to send in single formated, what is the problem with all other different formats?

Comment: Let me try explaining using an analogy. Consider a code snippet in javascript (or any other language). The code in itself can have logical constructs and variables of different types. But the code in itself has to be stored(encoded) in plain-text format. When you transfer the file containing the code, say from your pc to another, it is essentially a text file transfer. Hope this makes it clear.

Answer (score 2):

> why we are using only string type of JSON

Uhm, we're not. I believe you're misunderstanding something here. HTTP responses can really contain anything; every time you download a PDF or an image from a web server, the web server is sending a binary payload, which can literally be anything. So it's not even true that all HTTP bodies must be text.

To exchange data between systems, you send bytes. For these bytes to mean anything, you need an encoding scheme. Image formats have a particular way in which bytes need to be arranged, and when properly doing so, you can send pictures with them. Same for PDFs, video, audio, and anything else (including text).

If you want to send structured data, you need to express that structure somehow. How do you send a, for example, PHP array over HTTP…? (Substitute your equivalent list data structure in your language of choice.) You can't. A PHP array is a specific data structure in memory of a PHP runtime, sending that as is over HTTP has no meaning (because it deals with internal pointers and such). This array needs to be *serialised* first. There are many possible serialisation methods, some of them using binary data, and some using formats which are human readable to varying degrees. You could simply join all array elements with commas and `.split(',')` them again on the other end, but that's rather simplistic and misses many more complex cases and edge cases.

JSON and XML (and YAML and whatnot) are human readable formats which can serialise data structures like arrays (and dictionaries and numbers and booleans etc), and which happen to be text-based (purposely, to make them developer-friendly). You *can* use any of those data types JSON allows. Nothing prevents you from doing so, and not using them is insane. JSON and XML also happen to be two formats easily parsed with tools built into every browser. You *could* use any other binary format too, but then you'd have to manually parse it in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Communication between browser and server can be done in many ways. It's just that JSON comes out of the box. You can use protobuf, xml and plethora of other data serialization techniques to communicate with the server as long as both sides understand what's the communication medium. On the browser side, you have to probably implement protobuf, xml etc serialization/deserialization on your own in javascript.

Any valid JSON is permitted for data exchange. The keys are string quoted but the values can be strings, numbers, booleans, array or other objects itself. Though before transmission, everything is converted into a string and the receiving side parses it into the correct format.